# Erro no Laravel que não encontra uma rotina que existe

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

Está dando o erro abaixo no meu sistema em Laravel 5.4.  O que pode estar causando esse erro?

Já revisei e já rodei o comando: `php artisan clear-compiled`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue partes do código e suas respectivas classes.

<sub>**prefeitura.blade.php**</sub>

```
<h2> Lista de prefeituras</h2>
    @if ( !isset($criterio) )
      {{ $criterio = 'A'}}
    @endif
    @foreach(range('A', 'Z') as $letra)
      <div class="btn-group" style="width: 39px">
          <a  href="{{ route('prefeituras.search',$letra) }}" class="btn btn-primary {{$letra === $criterio ? 'disabled' : '' }}"   >
            {{ $letra }}
          </a>
        </div>    
      @endforeach
```

<sub>**PrefeituraController.php**</sub>

```
public function search(Request $request, $criterio = null) {
    //var_dump($letras);  
    if ( $criterio == null){
      $criterio = 'A';
    }
    //var_dump($criterio);
    $prefeituras = Prefeitura::indexSearch($criterio);
    return view('prefeituras', compact('prefeituras', 'criterio'))
                   ->with('i', ($request->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
  }
```

<sub>**web.php**</sub>

```
//Prefeitura
//Route::get('prefeiturassearch/{letra}','PrefeituraController@search');
Route::get('prefeituras/{letra}',[
    'as'   => 'prefeituras.search',
    'uses' => 'PrefeituraController@search']);
Route::resource('prefeituras','PrefeituraController');
```

Comment: Rafael, você precisa postar todas as partes relevantes do arquivo `PrefeituraController.php`, isso inclui a declaração dele, só remova os métodos que são dispensáveis.

Comment: é bom verificares o namespace do arquivo

Comment: Rafael experimenta na linha da viww onde está escrito {{route('prefeituras.search',$letra)}} colocar {{route('prefeituras.search',['letra'=>$letra])}} se der certo dá um alô para eu responder pois pode ser util para alguém. Obrigado!

Comment: Deves verificar o namespace pra ver se está de acordo com o RouteServiceProdiver.
Verificar o namespace na própria classe.
Verificar o nome do arquivo.
Verificar no routename na action que vai no arquivo de rotas (parece correta).

Comente o resource ali, provavelmente vai dar conflito. Coloque um prefix nesse resource pra evitar problemas, ou melhor, cria um arquivo de rotas para o backend e seta ele no RouteServiceProvider.